# How does a monitor arm hold the monitor in place after rotating to a new position?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Not sure if an example is needed, but [here is one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009S750LA).

[image]

I'm curious as to how the joint connected to the monitor itself "remembers" the last position the monitor was moved to. In my naiveté, I imagine the rotation being enabled by grease, so how is it that the monitor does not always rotate back towards the direction of gravity's pull?

Answer (score 1):

All the pivot joints are “stiff” due to being tightened sufficiently with friction so once in place they don’t move - except for flexing of the mechanism.